# What is the song playing in episode 453 of Naruto Shippuden at 16:15?

Tags: naruto, music

In episode 453 of *Naruto Shippuden*, there's a song playing at 16:15.

What is this song?

Answer (score 1):

Naruto Shippuden - Ochihabune

[Naruto Shippuden - Ochihabune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ly1NbCh5CD0)